# Replication/save conflicts of documents

Tags: lotus-domino, ibm-domino

I have two servers lets call them server A and B. In A, I have order documents and B is a replicate of A (A replicates to B every minute). In B, I have a java agent which is scheduled every 5 minutes and is sending a document to a website but also puts a flag in a field of the document. Many times now I get save/replication conflict on server A of that particular document which has been accessed by server B. This because others are also editing the same document on server A. How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the documents on A are created using a form, enable the "Merge conflicts" in form properties. If the documens are created with an agent, add a reserved field `doc.~$ConflictAction = "1"`.

Comment: Changing the design isn't sufficient by itself. You must run an agent against all existing documents to add the $Conflicts item. And you have to be careful about when you run the agent, because if users or other agents are modifying documents at the same time that the agent is running, you will get conflicts!